# How can I create stripe token on Backend Nest.js or Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, nest

I am trying to create Stripe Token on Backend Nest.js but I'm unable to create one from my customer card information. I am following the official strip documentation.

Here is my code

```
const token = await stripe.tokens.create({
  card: {
    number: '4242424242424242',
    exp_month: 10,
    exp_year: 2024,
    cvc: '314',
  },
});
```

This is taken from stripe [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card?lang=node) /

The error I am getting is

```
{
  "statusCode": 402,
  "message": "Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see https://stripe.com/docs/testing. To enable raw card data APIs in test mode, see https://support.stripe.com/questions/enabling-access-to-raw-card-data-apis."
}
```

How can I create token? I need it to create Payment Method.

Also, I am using Stripe API without its UI elements so my second confusion is should the token be created on Frontend or Backend?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice ? Search "Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe" in the search bar of Stack Overflow, this question has already been answered.

Comment: Sending raw card number is only allowed if you complete [SAQ-D](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide) or are certified with PCI level 1. Otherwise, Elements or Checkout Session should be used.